# vscode.dev. Can I write to the console in some way?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to write to a console on vscode.dev like with **Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")**;

I'm trying to make some beginner C# tuts, and would like to skip the install IDE part in the beginning, and focus on the language for now.

I'm sorry, can't seem to find any info about this, other than:

*"Run and Debug are not available in the web editor. To run and debug, you will need to continue in an environment that can run code, like a codespace or local VS Code."*

I was hoping for a simple runtime like here [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/numbers-in-csharp?WT.mc_id=Educationalcsharp-c9-scottha&tutorial-step=1)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. As your cited text clearly states, `vscode.dev` cannot execute code.